# How to send XML as form field using CURL

Tags: xml, bash, curl

I'm trying to POST to a url, sending form data and one of these fields takes an XML. The problem is that when this is executed the first '<' from the XML is being executed to redirect the output of the command rather than just use it as a plain text string. How do I send that in a bash script?

This is the relevant part of my sendcurl.sh:

```
tags='<Tagging><TagSet><Tag><Key>TagName</Key><Value>TagValue</Value></Tag></TagSet></Tagging>'
curl   -x http://localhost:8080                         \
    -# -k                       \
    -F key=$targfile            \
    -F acl=$acl                 \
    $key_and_sig_args           \
    -F tagging=$tags  \
    -F "Policy=$p"              \
    -F "Content-MD5=$md5"       \
    -F "Content-Type=$mime"     \
    -F "file=@$srcfile"         \
    https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/
```

I tried with several different values in $tags but the output is always the same:

```
no such file or directory: Tagging...
```

Any ideas on how to pass that as a form field?

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Also, you're just missing the quotes around `"$tags"`

Answer (score 0):

None of your `-F` options are surrounded by double quotes, which is what would be suggested.  Usually, that wouldn't be a problem, but if you have characters in the string that could be misinterpreted by the shell (like spaces, less than or greater than signs, etc) then you're going to have problems.

In this case, you simply need to change this line:

```
   -F tagging=$tags
```

to this:

```
   -F tagging=\"$tags\"
```

Note that you have to escape the double quotes, so the shell will allow them to go through unparsed.

Here's what the relevant portion of the curl command looks like after doing that:

```
 -F tagging="<Tagging><TagSet><Tag><Key>TagName</Key><Value>TagValue</Value></Tag></TagSet></Tagging>"
```